# Show JFrame fullscreen at Design Tab - WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm a bit new on design when it comes to WindowBuilder plugin. My application only runs at full screen and I know how to set my screen to full when it runs but I would like to know how I can design it at full screen on the "Design" tab.
Anyone can help me out?

Interface image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

WindowBuilder puts `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300)` in your constructor by default.....remove this and replace it with `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`  When you go back into design view, your window should be bigger to reflect that it is fullscreen.